# androidTest Groovy analog in build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When testing migrations in Android Room it is needed to add this Groovy code to build.gradle file

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        // Adds exported schema location as test app assets.
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
}
```

I am using Gradle Kotlin DSL, so I have Kotlin instead of Groovy for Gradle files (build.gradle.kts) and I can't find analog of androidTest there (androidTest is not resolved). What is androidTest and what will be analog of this piece of code in Kotlin script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've tried the following, which I've found [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/443) and it adds the directory.

```
sourceSets {
    getByName("androidTest").assets.srcDirs("$projectDir/schemas")
}
```